# domain server shows the error "currently there are no logon server available now"?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, windows-server-2012

In my domain server while entering the password is shows the error msg

> "there are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request".

Sometimes I restart my system I didn't enter the password for an half an hour after that I typed means sometimes it will opened. But it won't work most of the time.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: When you get that message it means your pc has not contacted your DHCP server therefore it hasn't contacted your DC wait a few minutes when you boot your computer and you'll be able to login . Also set your IP to static and see if it logs in without the error

Answer (score 0):

There is [guide from Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961826.aspx) to truoblechoot Active Directory problems.

Follow this algorithm and you find the problem.
[image: Active Directory troubleshoot algorithm]